# Clone command help wanted

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have created a Mech that I intend to make move using the clone command. I want to clone the position of the mech then make it appear a couple blocks in front of it. So far I can clone the mech but for some reason it won't appear in front it just says blocks cloned.This is the command I have.
[image]

I have it so that it should go 10 blocks in the Z direction but it doesn't happen please help!

Comment: are you sure your coordinates cover the mech? because they don't cover the commandblock you're looking into. plus the target location is relative to the commandblock, not the mech. also, you have too many coordinates, the syntax is `/clone <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <x> <y> <z> [maskMode] [cloneMode] [TileName] [dataValue|state]`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your clone syntax is wrong. Assuming the command block contains the correct relative coordinates to target the mech, the correct command should be:

`clone ~3 ~3 ~2 ~9 ~7 ~5 ~3 ~3 ~13 replace move`

Just be careful not to execute this twice in a row: if you do, your mech will be overwritten with air blocks. :) In other words, you can only move the mech once with this command. You'll need to use a different command or to move the command block 10 blocks in the Z direction manually if you want it to work a second time.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ~12 instead of ~13?